# Keep patch location after execute command in netlogo

Tags: netlogo, patch

How can I save the location of a patch after I have executed some command?

example:

```
ask myteam[ 

     set turtle-food-value patch-food-value; save the value of food into turtles
     set location patch-here

          if turtle-food-value != 0
          [let x1 max [turtle-food-value] of myteam   ; max for group
           set best-food x1

           .......
          ]
```

how to get or save x1's location?   (Since x1 return number instead of location)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: the turtle that knows about the value of the best food also knows about the location, It's unclear from your code extract how that is being stored.

Comment: is there any way to save location each time turtles found `patch-food-value`, so that I can extract the value of patch + its location? ( By storing `patch-food-value` and `location`)

Comment: If you just want the best, have a variable for the quality and another variable for the location. That was in the answer to your previous question. When you want to keep all the food values found and their locations, those variables will be lists. But you really need to get the easy version working properly before trying to write the hard version, to help you sort out the concepts and the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are really wanting to do is work out which turtle has found the best food and then get both the value and location of that food from the turtle. The way you have tried to do it takes the best value, but doesn't remember which turtle had it so you don't know which turtle to query for the location. You want the primitive `with-max` to identify the turtle and then ask that turtle for the food value and location.

Comment: Yess~! this is the one I need,thanks for your time, just two words have really solve my problem.